# How to create a process for each directory?

Tags: python, process, directory, fork

I'm having a hard time trying to create **child processes** for every folder in the current directory to execute certain function on them (Python 2.7).

My idea is to:

- First get all the folders with **os.listdir(path)** and filter the files with **os.path.isdir(file_path)**.
- Count the folders and calculate how many **forks** are needed, **e.g:** for 5 folders I'd need 3 forks (2³ - 1 = 7 child processes)
- Iterate through the number of needed forks and in each iteration execute the code for the folders, two at a time, getting their paths from a list containing all the folder paths.

  ```
  for counter in needed_forks:
     folder_pid = os.fork()
     if pid:
        some_function(folder_list[counter])
     else:
        some_function(folder_list[counter+1])
  ```

I can't get any good output mostly due to, I think, one index of the folder_list repeating in each iteration.
Any help is really appreciated, I'm rushing on this assignment, trying to learn multiprocessing and Python at once.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you need `counter*2` and `counter*2+1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have one process keep forking? Then you don't have to try to calculate the number of forks to use:

```
for d in directories:
    if os.fork():
        # parent
        continue
    else:
        # child
        # handle d...
        break # don't keep going
```

Of course, I'd question the wisdom of using `fork` to handle directories this way...

Comment: For the sake of time, I got it working that way with some minor modifications (`os._exit(0)` instead of `continue`). I guess it's just an exercise to get used to forking processes and then passing data through pipes. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, you should use `exit(0)` instead of `os._exit` since the latter is quite abrupt. But otherwise, good to hear!